# how to bind a jquery event handler on a jquery post returned data

Tags: jquery, events, post

I have a problem first let me explain what I expect my code to do.

I have a form with selects that depends on data selected from the select above it.

Let's say the form is creating a `menu_item`

The first select should ask the user of the menu type. It's options are - single article, article list, category view.

If the user selects single article as an option, the form should populate a select field below which should show all articles from the database. Likewise to all other menu type options.

At this point I managed to write jQuery code with the change method that posts to the server and query the database for the relevant option list data (let's say articles) depending on the menu type selection. And the data is returned as expected.

The problem is I want to still be able to bind a change method to the returned data so I can still be able populate the link field with the right article selected above.

But whatever I do there is no response whatsoever. Be it `$.change`, `$.click` methods won't work on the returned data above. When I checked the dom using firebug, I saw the div where the returned data was inserted, was blank even though in the browser the data was showing.

How do I bind jQuery event listener to its returned data?

The html of the returned data is processed from the server, so must I use the inline call to a listener function from the data html on the server?

Please help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the reason is that you are using .bind or simple .change method, for elements that do not exist yet on page (appended only after ajax call).

You should use .on method with delegated events approach (or for jquery 1.7 and older you may use .live method )

```
$("#container_div").on("click", "#list_id li", function(event){
    //list element clicked
});
```